# At what index I have to add --select name-- in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I have dropdownlist,which get filled from table1.That table1 has Zero value.While filling the dropdown,want to add "--select Name--".But at what index I have to add the select Name.I can not add it at -1 position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert the '--Select Name--' at index 0 but with value -1, and then you can check the value -1 later to identify your '--Select Name--' item.

```
YourDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--", "-1"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You Insert the text it at 0

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name---", "0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any item in the drop down list, thats why you are getting -1 as index. First make sure your data access to db is working correctly. Later you can insert in the dropdownlist at index 0. 
Something like.

```
dropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Name", "0"));
```

You can use add method to add to drop downlist

```
dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Name From db", "1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are open Jquery then you can try

```
$("#DropDownListId").prepend("<option value='0'>Select Name</option>").val('');
```